# Entity Framework TPT - Insert sub-type for existing base-type

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, poco

I am running into a problem where I want to insert a record for a sub-type with an existing record for the base-type.

The base-type may be a Person entity described by:

```
public class Person {
    [Key, Column("Id"), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
}
```

with the sub-type described by: (updated: didn't really have Id field here too)

```
public class Employee : Person {
    public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }
}
```

My create can be illustrated by this:

```
var employee = new Employee
    {
       Id = 1,
       HireDate = DateTime.Now
    });

context.Employees.Add(employee);
context.SaveChanges();
```

The SQL Server database, has two tables, Persons and Employees which has a foreign key between the Id fields and the Person.Id is autogenerated.

```
-----------             -------------
| Persons |             | Employees |
-----------             -------------
| Id      |   1 to 0..1 | Id        |
-----------             -------------
```

While this is like an EF-Code First, I am implementing it manually by writing the POCO's and then creating the tables in SSMS by hand.

Now, there is a person record with Id = 1. When I try to create a new Employee, and assign the Id as 1, Entity Framework is ignoring my Id assignment and inserting a brand new Person record, using the generated Id from that to assign Id of the Employee table.

How do I create an employee record using an/relating to an existing person record? I'm really trying to explore this idea. But, if it's not possible: What is an alternative to this?

Comment: You can't do that with EF. The scenario you are explaining is more like 1 to 0.1 from Person to Employee rather than inheritance.

Comment: By using TPT you just say that in one table you want to insert different objects which has in common some fields. Than the entity framework will create a table which has one column for each field and a last column of discriminator which tells you what kind of object is stored in that field. You cannot convert one object to another.

Comment: @IvanStoev yes you are correct in your explanation of the relationship being 1 to 0...1. Thank you! I will update the question. Are you positive this can't be done with EF?

Comment: When modeled as inheritance, an entity is either a `Person` *or* an `Employee`. I.e. you can't insert a second record representing the same `Person`. If a `Person` should become an `Employee` you have to delete the `Person` and insert a new `Employee`.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about inheritance here and model it as one to one relationship.

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }
}


var person = new Person { BirthDate = DateTime.Now };

var employee = new Employee
{
    Person = person,
    HireDate = DateTime.Now
};

context.Employees.Add(employee);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you use the function `Add`, you are informing your `DbContext` that a new Employee is being inserted into the database and that your `DbContext` should generate a new value for the primary key of the your new Employee.

If it was allowed to provide an Id when adding a new item, then you could create two different Employees, both referring to the same Person. Changing the Birthday of one Employee would result in changing the Birthday of the other Employee. Surely you wouldn't want this.

Hence: when Adding an item to the DbSet, DbContext will translate this into a SQL Insert statement, which ignores your provided Id.

> How do I create an employee record using an existing person record?

You specified that an Employee "is" a Person, not "has" a Person. If you create a new Employee object, you create also new Person-data. This is by object oriented design. It has nothing to do with databases. If you want a new Employee object with the same values for its Person properties, you'll have to copy the Person properties.

If you want the concept to have a new Employee without a new Person, then you should not derive, but aggregate. For Employee-Person this is a fairly strange concept, but for Employee-Address it is quite normal: An Employee lives on an Address. A new Employee might live on the same Address. You can create a new Employee and give it the same Address (not a copy!) of the original Employee. The effect is that you'll have two Employees, both having the same Address. You can even give one of the Employees a different Address, which won't effect the Address of the other Employee.